# Calculate Ratio of Current and Previous Week per Task Type

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am fairly new to `PowerBI` and coming form an `R` background, I have some difficulties understanding how `PowerBI` decides in which context a measure is evaluated.

I have the following measures, which calculates the ratio between the previous and the current week:

```
AHT               = DIVIDE(SUM('Daily Tasks'[SHT]), SUM('Daily Tasks'[#Tasks]))
AHT Current Week  = CALCULATE([AHT], 'Dates'[Date] >= TODAY() - 7)
AHT Previous Week = CALCULATE([AHT], 'Dates'[Date] < TODAY() - 7 && 'Dates'[Date] >= TODAY() - 14)
AHT Ratio Week    = DIVIDE([AHT Current Week], [AHT Previous Week])
```

So far so good.  Now I want to display the smallest ratio in a card visual (together with the task type which features this ratio) . Thus, I created the following 2 measures:

```
Top of the Week % = 
    MAXX(
        TOPN(
            1,
            SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
                'Daily Tasks'[Task Type],
                "Ratio", [AHT Ratio Week]
            ),
            [Ratio], ASC
        ),
        [Ratio] - 1
    )
Top of the Week = 
    CONCATENATEX(
        TOPN(
            1,
            SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
                'Daily Tasks'[Task Type],
                "Ratio", [AHT Ratio Week]
            ),
            [Ratio], ASC
        ),
        [Task Type],"  -  "
    )
```

The visual shows the correct values and all seems fine. However, if I either select a task type in any of the other visuals, or use a slicer to filter but a single task type, the card visual shows an error saying that

> SummarizeColumns and AddMissingItems must not be used in this context

So apparently something is amiss. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMMARIZECOLUMNS does not support evaluation within a context transition. This makes it almost impossible to use in a measure. You will want to use Summarize instead.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the clarification. I played with `SUMMARIZE` but I was not able to avoid `[Task Type]`s which yielded a `BLANK` ratio. Could you elaborate a short example how to implement such a measure and I'd gladly accept this answer?

Comment: Your first parameter should be the table name ‘Daily Tasks’. Your second parameter would be ‘Daily Tasks[Task Type]. Then you would be calculating a ratio for each type.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint of @Randy Minder I was able to solve the issue:

1. `SUMMARIZE` instead of `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` did the trick.
2. I just needed to filter out `BLANK` values and ended up with the following code:

```
Top of the Week % = 
    MAXX(
        TOPN(
            1,
            FILTER(
                SUMMARIZE(
                    ALL('Daily Tasks'[Task Type]),
                    'Daily Tasks'[Task Type],
                    "Ratio", 
                    [AHT Ratio Week]
                ),
                NOT(ISBLANK([Ratio]))
            ),
            [Ratio],
            ASC
        ),
        [Ratio] - 1
    )
```